# server for mobile applications

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, cloud

I am looking into building a server that will send/receive data from mobile/web apps. I'm wondering what would be the best language/environment to build this with.

The server will receive data regularly from the client apps and will hopefully push data to the clients in real time.

I'm not sure how the servers usually communicate with their mobile clients. Would I just use HTTP? Or should I look at another protocol?

If the server were to sit on the "cloud", for example AWS - what should I write it in? I could write a compiled program to sit here and dish out data? Perhaps Java? Though I'm not sure I like java. How about Python/rails?

I have never written a networked application before, so I'm not sure what the standard methods are here. So any advice from someone more experienced would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to push data to devices even when your app is not active, i.e. waking your app with new data?

Comment: Preferably, but it would not be critical I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the android tag, I would recommend [Google AppEngine](http://appengine.google.com/). There was a session in Google I/O 2011 about that. [Google I/O 2011: Android + App Engine: A Developer's Dream Combination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U)

Comment: The system we're developing requires android, iOS, and blackberry apps - it has to be available to everyone. Along with a web interface for certain features. Thanks for the link though, I will look into it.

Comment: You can build a REST web service in google app engine without any problem. You could them use this web service for you android, blackberry and ios apps. More info here: http://blog.noelios.com/2009/04/11/restlet-in-the-cloud-with-google-app-engine/